# make a device for USB ejection

Tags: usb, windows

I want to make a device for USB which is connected through usb to PC and offers an usb port.
The device should have a button which ejects (in Windows) the device plugged at the port of the device.

After some  research...
First I wanted to solve this problem through a [C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13530/Eject-USB-disks-using-C) program- but I really have no idea how to access through C# on "my button".
(the project's code isn't available anymore-if you know where I could get it-I would be really really happy.)

So I did some more research...
now I plan to use the WinAPI in combination with some C to accomplish this...(writing a device driver using the [KMPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(Kernel module of windows).

→But: I'm completly new to this.

How should I start?

Any suggestions/links which microcontroller would be good for this?

Is it possible to use the WinAPI (KMPF) to access on hardware input/my device's button?

Comment: If you could call windows APIs from a USB device, merely plugging in any USB device would give you instant access to everything on the computer. You will need a program running on the computer for this to work; in which event, why do you want a physical device at all?

Comment: well- I want a physical device because it would make it easier, faster and more comfortable to remove an usb device "safe"

Comment: In that case, look for any of a large number of "usb single button keyboard" projects, replicate that, then make your Windows app bind to the key combination your "keyboard" emits.

Comment: By "button" you mean a software button?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I mean a hardware button

Comment: @NickJohnson wow, I really haven't thought about such a possibility... then- how can I get a device that's linked at my device?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow - what do you mean by "linked at my device"?

Comment: First of all you will need a USB controller on your device, such that you could write a driver for it, right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes- right

Comment: @leAthlon So do you have one in mind?

Comment: @EugeneSh. not yet- a reason why I'm here

Comment: Are you saying you want a hub that can be commanded using a software button in Windows to disconnect any devices plugged into it?

Comment: As I understand this, you want the button to trigger windows to safely unmount the mass storage device on that particular USB port?

Comment: @Jon I think it's right except the button is hardware.

Comment: @Jon yes something like that, depending on the size I get the device to work, I might make a small version as attachement for an usb stick

Comment: @pjc50  yes that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MCU with USB interface can be chosen. The button will be a interrupt to the MCU. The MCU will be connected to the PC as a slave. Whenever the user presses the button (which is interfaced to the MCU) the associated firmware can raise a request to the application running on PC. The application later can handle the USB safe removal process.

This involves both hardware and software design and hence might not be efficient for quick prototype.

Comment: can you give an example for a good MCU?

Comment: @leAthlon That is subjective. STM32 series have a few USB ones. And ofcourse many from other vendors too. Full requirements should help in selecting a final MCU. I would personally go for one which had broad user community and rich software driver availability

Comment: @leAthlon STM32F4DISCOVERY board can be used. I believe you are okay with firmware that has to be developed on PC side